# Mirrored Object Not being Mirrored

Tags: mirror

when i press the mirror modifer nothing happens to my shape im a noob at blender so could someone please help? i've tried all other solutions that related to my post but none of them worked. [image]

Comment: You'll notice you have no mirror object.  Try playing around with that.  In fact, try watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LwQO_tWTAQ or this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7ArlYDNi-A which is simpler.

Comment: @user1833028 You don't always need a mirror object.

Comment: Oh sorry.  Sometimes I'm romantic about experimentation :P

Comment: You're trying to mirror on the wrong axis. You're object is cut around the Y, not X axis.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/mirror-modifier-is-not-working-no-mirrored-object

Answer (score 2):

The axis of symmetry used by the [mirror modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html?highlight=mirror) is the object's origin (orange dot).  [image]

If  your object has the origin at the center of the object the mirror modifier's effect will not be visible.

Go into edit mode, displace the geometry on the desired axis to one side of the origin, and the mirror modifier's effect will be noticeable.

Pay attention also to the which axis the modifier is acting on.

[image]