# Why isn't this mirror modifier working?

Tags: mirror

I try to add a mirror as modifier, but it just doesn't work and I don't know why please help me, I start a new file then go unto Add Modifier and choose Mirror, change nothing and click apply but nothing happens

Comment: Do you have your object selected, and applying while in *object mode*?

Comment: You're going to need to add more details to your question

Comment: Seems like you are adding a Mirror modifier without changing origin point of the object. Many generating modifiers work taking that into account, consider reading [wiki page for Mirror modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html).

Comment: rlated: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42102/mirrored-object-not-being-mirrored/42103#42103 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/mirror-modifier-is-not-working-no-mirrored-object

Answer (score 1):

The **Mirror modifier** mirrors the object about it's origin and merges the vertices that are within the `Merge Limit` of each other.

If you've just started a new session with the default Cube, then the cube's origin is in the center of the cube.  If that is your setup, you aren't going to see anything interesting unless you either:

- move the origin of the cube elsewhere: try moving the cube object, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Location*
- or start editing the actual mesh itself in Edit mode (select cube, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and start moving vertices around.)

If adding modifier after these actions you'll see some difference.

The aforementioned suggestions aren't really a good use of the modifier, but they'll help you see that it's actually active and working on your scene.  If you are wanting to look at a modifier to see what it does (or what multiple instances of it might do), may I suggest you take a look at the **Array modifier**?

---