# mirror modifier doesnt work

Tags: modifiers, mirror

Help I want to mirror something in blender with mirror modifier but then happens that[image]

I use blender 2.78a

Comment: @CraigDJones Please write your comment as an answer so it can be voted on and accepted!

Comment: Without a blend file, I am only making a suggestion and not offering an 'answer'. I'd prefer to wait until we hear back from the OP if it worked, no?

Comment: @Tookee also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/mirror-modifier-is-not-working-no-mirrored-object

Comment: @CraigDJones I think it is much better to answer based on the information available and let the asker and others assess it and vote/accept etc based on whether it helps them or not. You can always edit or answer again if it turns out not to solve the problem. There are too many questions on this site with answers hidden in the comments which makes searching etc a pain.

Comment: Okay, last time I did that I got a different instruction to post as comment instead. Edited to an 'answer'.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you first have applied transforms (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) , and then make sure you have your object center on the center line of the grid. You can do this by snapping the cursor to the object's center (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selection*) in Object mode and then snapping the object to the cursor with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor* in Edit mode.

Then in Edit mode move your geometry to align to where it should be on one side of origin point by X axis; the Mirror modifier should show the mirrorred part on the opposite side. If mirrored part has to be connected to original enable *Clipping* in Mirror modifier settings.

Comment: I have included [shortcuts formatting](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users) and some improvements; if I understand correctly you move object to origin point (I'd say it's faster to do the other way around). If I misunderstood your answer feel free to edit further.